# Command line address calculator?

Tags: address

I'm looking for a command line address calculator, where I can put in my private exponent and get out a bitcoin address in Base-58 encode. Does anyone know some free software that will allow me to do this? Basically like http://brainwallet.org/ but off line.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've cached a [command line Bitcoin address generator](https://gist.github.com/colindean/5239812) posted a while ago on BitcoinTalk. Note that I've not tested it more than once, but it should at least give you a place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Using openssl, you can convert private keys to public keys from the command line. The following command gives you the public key from a known private key. Part of it is from the same script that has been posted on BitcoinTalk some time ago and referred in [this](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/8900/5740) answer.

The private key should be in the form of a PEM file like this:

```
$ cat private_key.pem

-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
MHQCAQEEIMURrYd6CTHlrrV0JOxnze9ldaq3mRYMnYJ8195GldAVoAcGBSuBBAAK
oUQDQgAEANPTV3v+8AMXnIPaerOWziyc6tHbmbhORhbVKv1ACYuO+ohlFaV6QaOz
/AGjoSXV0ZeKxq7FijsAdBzeu23Fgg==
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----
```

**Note:** if you have a private key in hex format, then you should convert it to PEM format, using the procedure described [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/66594/signing-transaction-with-ssl-private-key-to-pem).

As said, to obtain the public key from the private key we use openssl:

```
$ openssl ec -pubout /dev/null

-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MFYwEAYHKoZIzj0CAQYFK4EEAAoDQgAEANPTV3v+8AMXnIPaerOWziyc6tHbmbhO
RhbVKv1ACYuO+ohlFaV6QaOz/AGjoSXV0ZeKxq7FijsAdBzeu23Fgg==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

In order to convert a public key to a bitcoin address, we need some [steps](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Technical_background_of_version_1_Bitcoin_addresses#How_to_create_Bitcoin_Address):

First we need to **compute the hash160** of the public key. This can be done as follows:

```
$ openssl ec -pubout /dev/null |
  openssl ec -pubin -pubout -outform DER 2>/dev/null |
  tail -c 65 |
  openssl dgst -sha256 -binary |
  openssl dgst -rmd160 -binary |
  xxd -p -c 80

ab085c55b735d4a811df3f55e6508634f1ce1e27
```

Then the hash160 has to be used to **calculate the checksum** as follows:

```
$ echo -n "ab085c55b735d4a811df3f55e6508634f1ce1e27" |
  xxd -p -r |
  openssl dgst -sha256 -binary |
  openssl dgst -sha256 -binary |
  xxd -p -c 80 |
  head -c 8

7801f8dc
```

The hash160, combined with the checksum and with the first byte "00", can be **encoded using base 58**. This gives us the address:

```
base58=({1..9} {A..H} {J..N} {P..Z} {a..k} {m..z})

encodeBase58() {
    # 58 = 0x3A
    bc 0) { n%3A ; n/=3A }" |
    tac |
    while read n
    do echo -n ${base58[n]}
    done
}
```

```
$ printf "%34s\n" "$(encodeBase58 "00$1$(checksum "$char$1")")" |
  sed "y/ /1/"

1GbLZiNzi7DTB4UowMuyqJw5Bh95yCbu3R
```

**Putting all together**, we can use the function publicKeyToAddress, as defined below. This can be part of a bash script, or you can type it on the command line.

```
base58=({1..9} {A..H} {J..N} {P..Z} {a..k} {m..z})

encodeBase58() {
    # 58 = 0x3A
    bc 0) { n%3A ; n/=3A }" |
    tac |
    while read n
    do echo -n ${base58[n]}
    done
}

checksum() {
    xxd -p -r /dev/null |
    tail -c 65 |
    openssl dgst -sha256 -binary |
    openssl dgst -rmd160 -binary |
    xxd -p -c 80
    )
}
```

```
$ openssl ec -pubout /dev/null | publicKeyToAddress

1GbLZiNzi7DTB4UowMuyqJw5Bh95yCbu3R
```